# Histogram: All bins have 0 length

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a histogram in d3. After manipulating a larger dataset, I am left with the following dataset, which are scores ranging from 0 to 10.

`m_data = [6, 9, 5, 6, 7, 5, 8, 7, 4, 7, 4, 3, 5, 8, 5, 4, 8, 7, 6, 9, 4, 6, 8]`

The problem is that the bins created from our "binmaker" do not bind data from `m_data` to respective bins.

We create bins using `m_data`. We use 10 ticks (0-10). Very little information is floating around surrounding specific problems for histograms in D3 v5.

```
var dataP = d3.json("classData.json");
dataP.then(function(data)
{
  drawChart(data);

})

var drawChart = function(data)
{

  // dimensions //
  var screen =
  {
    width: 500,
    height: 400
  }

  var margins =
  {
    top:10,
    bottom:40,
    left:40,
    right:100
  }
  var width = screen.width-margins.left-margins.right;
  var height = screen.height-margins.top-margins.bottom;

  var day = 7;

  // data manipulation //
  var m_data = data.map(function(d) { return d.quizes[day+1].grade; });
  console.log(m_data);
  //create scales
  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0,10])
                .range([0,width])
                .nice();

  // create histogram and binmaker
  var binMaker = d3.histogram()
                .domain([xScale.domain()])
                .thresholds(xScale.ticks(10));
  var bins = binMaker(m_data); // how this is created? //
  // bins.shift();
  // bins.pop();

  // console.log("bin 0: " + bins[0].x0);
  console.log('bins',bins);

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(bins, function(d) { return d.length; } )])
                .range([height, 0]);

  // create svg
  var svg = d3.select("svg").attr("width",width)
                            .attr("height",height);
  svg.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
  svg.append('g').attr("transform","translate(0,"+height+")").call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));
  var plotLand = svg.append('g')
                    .classed("plot",true)
                    .attr("transform","translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

  // create dom elems for bins
  plotLand.selectAll('rect')
          .data(bins)
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("x",function(d) {return xScale(d.x0);})
          .attr("width",function(d)
          {
               return xScale(d.x1)-xScale(d.x0);
          })
          .attr("y",function(d){return yScale(d.length);})
          .attr('height',function(d)
          {
            return height - yScale(d.length);
          })






}
```

After creating our bins for the histogram, we run into the problem where all of our bins have length: 0; our`m_data` values are not placed into their respective bins.

Comment: I tried your code. It seems the `xScale` is not defined. Is this your complete code for the chart?

Comment: I apologize. I will update with entire code. I appreciate your help! @Coola

Comment: It is now updated @Coola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `domain` of the histogram generator it has to be [an array](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#bin_domain):

> The bin domain is defined as an array [min, max], where min is the minimum observable value and max is the maximum observable value.

However, you have this:

```
var binMaker = d3.histogram()
    .domain([xScale.domain()])
```

As `xScale.domain()` is itself an array:

```
[0,10]
```

You'll end up with:

```
var binMaker = d3.histogram()
    .domain([[0, 10])
```

Which obviously won't work. So, just do:

```
var binMaker = d3.histogram()
    .domain(xScale.domain())
    //no square brackets--^
```

Here is the demo:

```js
m_data = [6, 9, 5, 6, 7, 5, 8, 7, 4, 7, 4, 3, 5, 8, 5, 4, 8, 7, 6, 9, 4, 6, 8];
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 10])
  .nice();
var binMaker = d3.histogram()
  .domain(xScale.domain())
  .thresholds(xScale.ticks(10));
var bins = binMaker(m_data);
console.log(bins);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```